# Fatal Error Deploying Apex from Sandbox to Prod

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment

I made some small tweaks to an apex class in sandbox and all my unit tests passed in sandbox, I tried pushing the apex classes and the unit tests.

The error I'm getting is Fatal Error and that my code has no coverage. In sandbox, my code is north of 90%. The developer console doesn't give me any logs of the apex deployment so I can't debug there.

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**: The unit tests that cover this code are already live in production. When I validation the change set I run all of them

- SalesForecastCreateBatch_Test
- SalesForecastUpdateBatch_Test
- SalesForecastCreate_Controller_Test
- SalesForecastSchedulerTest

As you can see below the code coverage for both classes in sandbox are >= 90%.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What set of unit tests did you specify to run when you performed the deployment?

Comment: Odds are, you forgot to push the test class with the class.

Comment: Can you try with using alternate tools like the Force.com IDE, Workbench, ANT....

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to more clearly indicate what test settings you used during your deployment. Are you deploying the classes indicated? Are they new?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - done, apologies for being unclear. They are not new.

Comment: No apologies needed, down vote removed. Do the tests pass in your validation? In the live environment?

Comment: I found the issue, I forgot to include commas between the test classes. Rookie mistake. Thanks for the support

Comment: @kmomo If you could add that as an answer (again remember to be very detailed), that would add a lot of value to the community. Please also don't forget to accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following may be the reasons:

1. You have two classes mentioned in the error does not have 75% code coverage 
    in the org(production)
2. You have not included the test classes in the deployment that you are 
   currently doing and hence the system is looking for the 75% code coverage 
   for these classes in org which it calculates to be <75%

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've updated my post to give more information about the unit tests.

Comment: It can be xx% in sandbox , run the same test class in production and see whats the code coverage of the same , if you are inline with you sandbox before you deploy. Also if you want to avoid this issue , push these test classes along with your current deployment and specify these classes so that it will take the coverage from the current deployment

Comment: The issue was forgetting to include commas between the test classes, apologies for the jv move